Large $N$ method in QFT
I am trying to learn about the Large $N$ method in QFT. Is it a general algorithm that can be applied to any system, or does the technique vary depending on the system?
I would appreciate explanations and references to the Large $N$ method, as general as possible. I'd like to understand it and learn how to apply it.

https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0306133
